# How to validate a form by ajax before submit in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing it this way:

```
...submit(function() {
    $.post(...,function() {
         validate();
    })
});
```

But it turns out that the form is submitted directly...

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Here's an example on how it could be used:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        command: 'required'
    },

    messages: {
        command: 'Please enter a command.'
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(data) { /* ... */ },
            url: form.action,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it support server side validation?

Comment: No, usually the proper way is to do client-side validation first as it is much faster and *then* submit the form, either returning a success-response (which could e.g. redirect the user) or an error which is then also handled by your success callback.
If most of your clients have JavaScript enabled the server-side validation could be as simple as returning a "Some fields are invalid"-like error and rely on clientside validation for verbose errors

Comment: +1 for doing validation on the Client side. 99% of clients do enable Javascript, hence pretty & meaningfull validation errors can be handled Client Side. In some cases, you have no choice though & will have to to complex business logic on the server side (ie. access a Db & so on)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to grab each element and run it through your validation, then submit the form later.

Use `$(id).value` (for id-d elements) or `yourForm.someElementName.value` (for name-d elements, assuming your form is `name`d `yourForm`).

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent the default form submission

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if(valid())
  {
    $.post . . .
  }
});
```

Comment: I somehow have the feeling he's doing serverside validation.. i.e. submitting the form twice: once for validation and once for actual processing. IMO this is awful (but the struts-jquery plugin does something like that too); see my answer for a better client-side validation solution.

Comment: Yes,I'm doing server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to AJAXily do server side validation without posting the form to another page, you could do something like this. Instead of binding the validation action to submit, you could instead make your "submit" button just a "button" type, and then bind your validation to it's click event. Once it passes validation, then you can move on.

For instance:

```
$('#myPseudoSubmitButton').click(function() {  
     // Send the form to the server side for validation  
     $.post('validation_script.php', { form inputs here }, function(data) {  
          if (data.validated) {
               // Perform some functionality that happens when the form validates
          }
          else {
               // Display an error message to the user
          }
     });
}, 'json');
```

This of course presupposes that your validation script returns JSON-formatted data with a "validated" attribute.